# CoreData: desired type = Towns; given type = Towns - Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship

Tags: core-data, model, nsmanagedobject, cloudkit, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I'm scratching my head since after a few hours I still can't understand this.

I have 2 entities in my Core Data model:

- Towns
- Restaurant

I have defined the relationship one to many and inverse.
(yep, you've got it, a Town can have multiple restaurants ;)

I'm using the Core Data Stack to persist elements from CloudKit and the AlecrimCoreData library. In a class that grab content from CloudKit, I create the context thanks to Alecrim:

```
let dataContext = DataContext()
```

Then I have a bunch of functions that call class functions to create the NSManagedObjects, if needed

```
let town = Towns.createTownsFromCK(record, dataContext: self.dataContext) ...
let restaurant = Restaurants.createRestaurantFromCK(record, dataContext: self.dataContext) ...
```

As you can see, I pass the dataContext to each call, so it's the same for Restaurants and Towns. CloudKit restaurant objects are grabbed after Towns have been locally saved.

```
try dataContext.save()

let restaurantPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "town == %@", record.recordID)
let restaurantQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "Restaurants", predicate: restaurantPredicate)
self.publicDB.addOperation(createQueryOperation(restaurantQuery, cursor: nil, resultblock:fetchedRestaurantsRecord))
```

When grabbed, I can create restaurant NSManagedObjects and add properties, but when I want to link the town, I get a strange error when I set the town:

```
if let cktownreference = record["town"] as? CKReference,
        town = dataContext.towns.filter{ $0.ckid! == cktownreference.recordID.recordName }.first {
    restaurant.town = town
 }
```

The error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: property = "town"; **desired type = Towns; given type = Towns**; value =  (entity: Towns; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: {
>       ckid = "6665ca0f-af57-4305-8e18-ced7540e6279";
>       name = Paris;
>       recordChangeTag = ii0l38hp;
>       restaurant = "";
>   }).'

I have tried to create a new context, I have tried to set the Town as an `NSSet`, same results.

Here is my Restaurant schema:

[image: Restaurant model & relationship]

And Town:

[image: Town model & relationship]

I'm having the same problem in every one:many link I have.

Comment: The `towns` method does not return the right type. Show the method called via `dataContext.towns` by editing your question.

Comment: Strange one, the debugger seems to give me a Town object

Comment: @Matthieu I'm getting this also. Have you had any luck fixing it?

Comment: Sorry @Dov for the delay. My solution was to replace the the framework I was using by plain old CoreData

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, that doesn't help me since I was using plain Core Data. Some voodoo helped me out - I changed around my data model, and then changed it back, and the errors went away.

Comment: This is a plain mistery!